# Can SQL Server table have a foreign key to a table that resolves to many records?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

Consider the following table...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Alerts]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [I18NMessageKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

and the following table...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[I18NMessages]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Culture] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

I would like to add a foreign key constraint to table `[Alerts]` on the column `[I18NMessageKey]` to refer to many records in table `[I18NMessages]`.

Is this possible without a third table?

The [I18NMessages] table holds the same message for the `[Key]` but in different languages depending on `[Culture]`.  The relationship between `[Alerts]` and `[I18NMessages]` doesn't care about the culture.  The resolution of `[Culture]` depends on the user at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, the uniqueness of the referenced key column(s) must be enforced by a primary key, unique constraint, or unique index. You need a third table with a unique I18NMessageKey column key to enforce referential integrity.

Comment: That's what I thought.  OK - thanks for the sanity check!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger and implement custom business logic

Comment: you could, but I wouldn't! Use a third table instead.